# CurrentTarget and target issue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using map in one of the component in React -

```
{ iconName.map(icon => (
       <button onClick={clickHandler} key={icon.id} className='nav__tab'>
           <Tabs iconName={icon.name} iconUrl={icon.src}/>
       </button>

))}
```

And in the Tabs component, I have

```
<div className='tabs'>
  <div>{ iconUrl }</div>
  <span className='tabs__name'>{iconName}</span>
</div>
```

And on the UI, it looks like this -

[[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trb97.png)]

**The problem** - Whenever I click on any button, I want to differentiate which button is clicked. Like when user clicks on Button1, I want to know that button1 is clicked and so on. I am not getting anything inside event on clickHandler function to differentiate the buttons.

I checked event.target inside the event, but when I click on SVG icon, it consoles null. And when I click on the text like button1, button2 it gives me the desired result. Only problem is when I click on SVG icons.

Comment: How are the svg icons being rendered? Your code above doesn't have an `<svg>` element, does it actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue of the `target` element being SVG, you can use `closest` method, but the easier way, you can pass the icon as a second parameter, and you will get the clicked `icon`.

```
{ iconName.map(icon => (
       <button onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e, icon)} key={icon.id} className='nav__tab'>
           <Tabs iconName={icon.name} iconUrl={icon.src}/>
       </button>

))}
```

Answer (score 0):

will need to pass the event to the function know wich is the target.
try:

```
{ iconName.map(icon => (
       <button onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)} key={icon.id} className='nav__tab'>
           <Tabs iconName={icon.name} iconUrl={icon.src}/>
       </button>

))}
```

You can pass the icon like second parameter to the function too.

Comment: Hi Thiago Lessa,
I have tried the same thing, but still currentTarget is null and there is no option in event.target from which I can differentiate which button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You have minimum 2 options here to get what you want:

1. Instead of checking if the clicked event matches a specific selector, you can check if it occurred within a selector using the `closest()` method.
2. You can disable clicking on SVGs so that the event fires on the parent button instead of the SVG and it’s child elements.  `svg { pointer-events: none;}`

For more information, you can refer: [Detecting click events on SVGs with vanilla JS event delegation](https://gomakethings.com/detecting-click-events-on-svgs-with-vanilla-js-event-delegation/).